# How can I find out the place of an artifact in groovy

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I have the following groovy dependency declared:

```
@GrabResolver(name='mymirror', root='http://myartifactory/public/')
@Grab(group='groupid', module='artifactid', version='1.2.3')
println //What should I write here to see: c:\Users....m2....artifactid.jar
```

How can I get the location of the downloaded resolved artifact in groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Grab(group='net.sourceforge.plantuml', module='plantuml', version='8049')
import groovy.grape.Grape

def grape = Grape.getInstance()
def r = grape.listDependencies(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
println r
println grape.resolve(r[0])
```

prints

```
[[group:net.sourceforge.plantuml, module:plantuml, version:8049]]
[file:/C:/Users/dm/.groovy/grapes/net.sourceforge.plantuml/plantuml/jars/plantuml-8049.jar]
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, [Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#Grape-Detail) stores a cache of the jars on `~/.groovy/grapes`. So, I think you can do something like this:

```
@GrabResolver(name='mymirror', root='http://myartifactory/public/')
@Grab(group='groupid', module='artifactid', version='1.2.3')

String grapeCacheDir = "${System.getProperty('user.home')}/.groovy/grapes"
String group = 'groupid'
String module = 'artifactid'
String version = '1.2.3'

File myJar = new File("$grapeCacheDir/$group/$module/jars/${module}-${version}.jar")
println myJar.path
```

It's not a preety solution, but I can't think in any other options.